# How to get key data from NSDictionary swift 4

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I want to get the result from `NSDictionary` i get this `NSDictionary` from webservice now i want to get the result .

i need this valuse     "Your request is unsuccessfull. Please "

i tried this `let ft = resultsm.value(forKeyPath: "Body.QR_FundTransferResponse.QR_FundTransferResult") as! String`  but is store data and print the same value for all request

```
let result:NSDictionary = dict! as NSDictionary 

The output is : 

  Body =     {
    "QR_FundTransferResponse" =         {
        "QR_FundTransferResult" = "Your request is unsuccessfull. 
       Please ";
          };
    };
```

Comment: Why NSDictionary instead of Dictionary and what is the content of the dictionary, I don’t understand what keys you have and what the structure of your values are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got this in a function and result is of type `[String: Any]` (e.g. a Dictionary):

```
guard let body = result["body"] as? [String: Any] else {
    // Failed to find body, return empty string
    return ""
}
guard let response = body["QR_FundTransferResponse"] as? [String: Any] else {
    return ""
}
guard let result = response["QR_FundTransferResult"] as? String else {
    return ""
}
// Now have "Your request is unsuccessful. Please "
return result
```

Recommend you check out `Codable`.

Comment: the output message doesn't clear it shows the previous message. @JonJ